# Non regex WSGI dispatcher

Tags: python, wsgi, middleware

I've found this [regex based dispatcher](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/urlrelay/) but I'd really rather use something that only uses literal prefix strings. Does such a things exist?

I know it wouldn't be hard to write but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 3):

[Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#routing) / [Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/documentation/dev/routing.html) has a phenomenal wsgi url dispatcher that is not regex based.  For example in Flask:

```
@myapp.route('/products/<category>/<item>')
def product_page(category, item):
    pseudo_sql = select details from category where product_name = item;
    return render_template('product_page.html',\
                      product_details = formatted_db_output)
```

This gets you what you would expect, ie., http://example.com/products/gucci/handbag ; it is a really nice API.  If you just want literals it's as simple as:

```
@myapp.route('/blog/searchtool')
def search_interface():
    return some_prestored_string
```

**Update:** Per Muhammad's question here is a minimal wsgi compliant app using 2 non-regex utilities from Werkzeug -- this just takes an url, if the whole path is just '/' you get a welcome message, otherwise you get the url backwards:

```
from werkzeug.routing import Map, Rule

url_map = Map([
    Rule('/', endpoint='index'),
    Rule('/<everything_else>/', endpoint='xedni'),
])

def application(environ, start_response):
    urls = url_map.bind_to_environ(environ)
    endpoint, args = urls.match()
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    if endpoint == 'index':
        return 'welcome to reverse-a-path'
    else:
        backwards = environ['PATH_INFO'][::-1]
        return backwards
```

You can deploy that with Tornado, mod_wsgi, etc.  Of course it is hard to beat the nice idioms of Flask and Bottle, or the thoroughness and quality of Werkzeug beyond `Map` and `Rule`.

Comment: Is it a wsgi dispatcher in the sense that it passes HTTP requests to a wsgi application? Or is it the same as `bottle` in my answer, expects functions that work with the particular framework?

Comment: See the second link, quickstart section. But yes, you could use the Werkzeug routing for pure wsgi dispatch only, you call the `bind_to_environ` method on the `Map` object with the request's wsgi environ as a parameter in your application and you're off and running -- you can have a wsgi compliant application with just `Map` and `Rule` in 6 lines of code.  The Flask stuff is just a nice set of utilities for working with those same objects in a more transparent way.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you describe, but your needs may be served by using [bottle](http://bottle.paws.de/). The `route` decorator is more structured. Bottle does not host WSGI apps, though it can be hosted as a WSGI app.

Example:

```
from bottle import route, run

@route('/:name')
def index(name='World'):
    return '<b>Hello %s!</b>' % name

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a few years, but here is my quick and dirty, drop-dead simple, solution.

```
class dispatcher(dict):
    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        key = wsgiref.util.shift_path_info(environ)
        try:
            value = self[key]
        except:
            send_error(404)
        try:
            value(environ, start_response)
        except:
            send_error(500)
```

Notes

1. We leverage the built-in 'dict' class to get a lot of functionality.
2. You need to supply the send_error routine.